# Inverse square law of sound

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, vibrations

How can I prove $1/r^2$ based on this equation (Intensity) based on the inverse square law of sound?

$I = 8 \cdot 10^{-9} \cdot r^{-1.303}$

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Nohow. $-1.3 \neq -2.0$, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the total power in the wave, and divide by the area over which it is distributed, as a function of radius.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse square law assumes that the wave is spreading out uniformly in three dimensions.  It would appear that the formula you have is for a directed wave (perhaps from a loud speaker).